# How do I create an alphabetically organized glossary of links?

Tags: list, customization, archive-template

Here is the kind of archive page I am trying to reproduce for my client:

http://www.catwalkyourself.com/page/ready_to_wear/autumn_winter12-13/rtw12_13.php

As you can see, it is a list of alphabetically organized lists. How would I go about creating this in Wordpress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the default Links section in the dashboard, then write a custom loop to sort them alphabetically (and with the rad big letters of the alphabet as headings).

Throw this in your theme's `functions.php` file, then use it on any page with the `[bookmarks]` shortcode:

```
function bookmarks_by_alphabet( ) {

    $letter = ''; // For tracking which letter of the alphabet we're at.
    $args = array(
        'category_name'  => '', // Category name of a category of bookmarks/links to retrieve. Leave this blank to get them all.
        'limit' => -1 // Show all. 
    );
    $output = '';   
    $links = get_bookmarks( $args );
    if ( $links ) {
        foreach ( $links as $link ){

            if ( $link->link_name[0] != $letter ){
                $letter = $link->link_name[0];
                $output .= '<h2>'.$link->link_name[0].'</h2>';
            } 
            $output .= '<a href="'.$link->link_url.'">'.$link->link_name.'</a>'.'<br />';
            //echo '<pre>'.print_r($link, true).'</pre>';
        }
    }

    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('bookmarks', 'bookmarks_by_alphabet');
```

Comment: You can use it in a custom template like so: `echo do_shortcode('[bookmarks]');`